# Can someone explain what these lines of code are doing?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit, bitmask

```
int64_t lstbt(int64_t val){ 
   int64_t msk = val&(val-1); 
   return log2(val^msk);
}
```

What does the `msk` actually computes, and why are we returning `log` of value `xor` `msk`?

Comment: `val&(val-1)` turns off rightmost set bit in val. `val^msk` produces the number with all bits 0, and 1 in the place of  rightmost set bit in val. `log2` gives its index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the function:

```
int64_t lstbt(int64_t val){ 
   int64_t msk = val&(val-1); 
   return log2(val^msk);
}
```

let us break it into smaller chunks.

First the statement `val-1`, by adding `-1` to `val`, you flip (among others) the least significant bit (LSB), (*i.e.,* `0` turns into `1`, and *vice-versa*).

The next operation (`val&(val-1)`) applies an "and" bitwise. From the `&` operator we know that:

```
1 & 1  -> 1
1 & 0  -> 0
0 & 1  -> 0
0 & 0  -> 0
```

So either

1. `val` was initially `...0`, and `val - 1` is ....1, and in this case `val&(val-1)` produces  `...0`;
2. or `var` was initially `...1`, and `var - 1` is ....0, and in this case `val&(val-1)` produces  `...0`;.

So in both cases, `val&(val-1)` set to `0` the `LSB` of `var`. Besides that, another important change that `val&(val-1)` does is setting to `0` the first rightmost bit set to `1`.

So let us say that val = xxxxxxxx**1**0000 (it could have been `xxxxxxxxx1000` as long as it showcases the right most bit set to 1), when `msk=val&(val-1)` then `msk` will be `xxxxxxxx00000`

Next, we have `val ^ msk`; a `XOR` bitwise operation, which we know that:

```
1 ^ 1  -> 0
1 ^ 0  -> 1
0 ^ 1  -> 1
0 ^ 0  -> 0
```

So because `val` will be something like `xxxxxxxx10000` and msk `xxxxxxxx00000`, where the bits represented with 'x' from `val` will match exactly those from `msk`; the result of  `val ^ msk` will always be a number with all bits set to `0` with exception for the only `bit` that will be different between `val` and `msk`, namely the right most bit set to `1` of `val`.

Therefore, the result from  `val ^ msk` will always be a value that is a power of 2 (except when `val` is 0). A value that can be represent by `2^y = x`, where `y` is the index of the right most bit set to 1 in `val`, and `x` is the result from `val^msk`. Consequently, `log2(val^msk)` gives back `y` *i.e.,* the index of the right most bit set to 1 in `val`.

Answer (score 1):

```
val&(val-1) # to figure out if value is either 0 or an exact power of two.
val^msk # cuts the part of power of 2 from val
log2 # finds the index of bit which set val^msk.
```

**so i guess the function you have `lstbt` is to find out how many times the `val` can divide on 2 with reminder 0.**